# Efficient way to iterate over an array for a specific member

Tags: c#, arrays, list

In my last project I have found myself iterating over many Arrays or Lists of strings in order to find a specific string within.

**I have got to ask, is there any way less than `O(n)` in order to find a specific member inside an array?**

An `O(n)` solution in C# (consider there are no duplicates):

```
foreach(string st in Arr)
{
   if (st=="Hello")
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Hey!");
      break;
   }
}
```

**EDIT : I didn't ask my question quite right. I wish to also change the member I wish to find and not only look him up.
So my snippet changes to:**

```
foreach(string st in Arr)
{
   if (st=="Hello")
   {
      st="Changed";
      break;
   }
}
```

Can you somehow get to `O(logn)`? If so, can you further explain how it is done and how is it more effiecient than my solution.
Thanks for any light on that matter!

Comment: Are you just going to do this once or many times? For a single access on an array or list O(n) is your best but if you do it many times you might be better off putting them into a different structure (eg sorting them first, putting them in a HashSet, etc.

Comment: You can use [`SortedList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I'm not sure what the order of operations is, but maybe using something like `Arr.Find(x => x == "Hey");` might be more efficient. I'm not sure how LINQ handles searching through an Array though.

Comment: Why not use hash structure?

Comment: Use for instead, is 2 times cheaper than foreach.

Comment: @Chris just once. Anyway- how would you sort an array of strings?

Comment: @Turrican: That is just nonsensical...

Comment: @RajatGarg can you further explain?

Comment: @Oranges: What do you mean how would you sort an array of strings? The same way you sort anything else?

Comment: @Chris For example, you can sort an array of ints by their value(From min to max), but strings might not be alphabetical..

Comment: @Oranges: for your use case, you just need to check if the string exists in a list or not. You can very well use a hashset and it will give you exists check in almost constant time.

Comment: `List<T>` and `Array` both have a `BinarySearch` method which would provide `O(log n)` search time, provided they are *sorted first*.

Comment: @Oranges: Ordering of strings is as well defined as it is of ints. The string class itself implements IComparable so you don't need to worry about any of that yourself.

Comment: How big are these arrays?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> is there any way less than O(n) in order to find a specific member
>   inside an array?

If you have a collection of strings with no regards to duplicates, and sort isn't a matter, you should use a `HashSet<T>`, where with a normal distribution you should be at `O(1)` for **lookups**:

```
var hashSet = new HashSet<string> { "A", "B", "C" };
if (hashSet.Contains("A"))
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("hey");
}
```

In case you need more than lookups, e.g accessing a member at a specific index, then `HashSet<T>` should not be your pick. You need to specify exactly what you're going to be doing with the collection if you want a more elaborate answer.

Comment: you can not insert duplicate in HashSet but you can in array

Comment: @dotctor Where did he say anything about duplicates? Although I added that as a comment.

Comment: That loses certain aspects of an array or list though, for one the ordering. That might not be important but you should really point out what might be lost by changing data type.

Comment: @dotctor: It is really not even a consideration... existence vs index.

Comment: also for small number of items array will be more efficient than HasSet

Comment: @Chris I see no where in his question where ordering is considered.

Comment: @dotctor: You should probably stop making irrelevant comments now.

Comment: I dont think talking about efficeincy in this question is irrelevant. @leppie

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What if I want to manipulate the specific "A" member instead of only checking for his existence?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: That is true but my point is that the OP cannot necessarily just replace his list/array with a hashset and assume that all other code will still work. Perhaps we can assume that the OP will go and look up hashsets and discover all the ins and outs themselves but at the same time I always prefer answers to highlight at least in brief, limitations that the solution might have. I should note that I have still upvoted, my comment was just because I personally think the answer would be improved by inclusion of that but I appreciate that is a subjective matter. :)

Comment: @Oranges If you need to be accessing a specific member by index, `HashSet<T>` isn't the way to go. You'll need to provide exactly what you want to do with your collection in order for me to provide a viable answer.

Comment: @Chris I made it clear with an edit. Thanks for the remark.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Sorry for misleading. Let's consider I want to find the member "A" inside the array and change it to "Hello".

Comment: @Oranges Then perhaps a sorted `List<string>` with `Array.BinarySearch` will do, assuming the list is of decent size.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Sorting a list and then Binary Searching it is more efficient than my own solution?

Answer (score 1):

There is a project called ["C5 Generic Collection Library"](https://www.itu.dk/research/c5/) at the University of Copenhagen. They have implemented an extended set of collection classes that may help you such as a HashSet that allows duplicates called hashbag and they have a hash-indexed array list which may prove useful...